# Why AlamofireImage caching does not work?

Tags: ios, swift, caching, alamofire, alamofireimage

I want to cache my images via Alamofire Image framework. For this I do:

```
let imageCache = AutoPurgingImageCache(
        memoryCapacity: 100 * 1024 * 1024,
        preferredMemoryUsageAfterPurge: 60 * 1024 * 1024
    )

    let URLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "\(credentials.postCoverURL)\(recentNews[indexPath.row].image)")!)

    let cachedCoverImage = imageCache.imageForRequest(
        URLRequest
    )

    cell.coverImage.image = cachedCoverImage
```

but it does not cache my images. Can anyone help me with it, why it does not cache my images? What I do wrong?

When I restart my app, images load/download again

Comment: You show us the requesting the image from the cache, but not the original `downloadImage` request that would have cached it (or as JustJasper suggests, your manual caching of it). Show us where/how you would have cached it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember adding the image to the cache?

```
imageCache.addImage(
    avatarImage, 
    forRequest: URLRequest
)
```